# Django Models QuerySet API issues

Tags: python, django

My models.py looks like this:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    pubdate = models.DateField()
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
```

I can get the list of `Publisher`s together with the publishing date of the latest `Book` they published using:

```
Publisher.objects.annotate(latest_book_pubdate=Max('book__pubdate'))
```

which will return

```
Publisher 1 name, book.pubdate(the latest pub)
Publisher 2 name, book.pubdate(the latest pub)
Publisher 3 name, book.pubdate(the latest pub)
Publisher 4 name, book.pubdate(the latest pub)
...
```

My question is, how can I also get the `name` of the latest published `Book`. My desired output is:

```
Publisher 1 name, book.name(the latest pub)
Publisher 2 name, book.name(the latest pub)
Publisher 3 name, book.name(the latest pub)
...
```

Comment: What have you tried? what does the list of random texts refer to? what is the annotation for?

Comment: Hi XueBai! Welcome to StackOverflow. Do include any code you have tried so we can help you diagnose your issue. Do note that SO is not a place for those who are here merely for answers without showing effort of having attempted resolving the issue themselves.

Comment: @XueBai, there can be multiple books with the same pubdate

Comment: @Selcuk, Assuming that Just one At the same time

Comment: @XueBai You can assume that, but Django won't. I don't think there is a simple way (other than looping and checking yourself) as `Max` is an aggregate function, similar to `Avg`.

Comment: Maybe you could create a `Rand` aggregate function. and use it to select a random book. Or otherwise set `unique_together = [('pubdate', 'publisher')]` in the metaclass.

Comment: @Selcuk, Thanks, I will be check myself